# Syntax Error When Accessing Variables in a Class

Tags: php, class, syntax-error

Why does this give me an error?

```
$this->_page->page_text = Messages::msg[$explode[1]];
```

The structure of `Messages` is

```
class Messages
{
    public static $msg = array(...);
    public static $ns = array(...);
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $explode is a variable containing some exploded data and you are using the 2nd item in that array as an index for your messsage, you need to use `Messages::$msg[$explode[1]];`

Variables always start with `$`

Comment: but the structure of $this->_page is a bunch of variables and I don't need to use $ on those

Comment: That's because $this is the variable. Message isn't a variable (its a class), so $msg has to be referenced as the variable since that is what it is.